# How To Add Via NuGet, Required Dlls To Command Line App That Connects To CRM?

Tags: nuget, dynamics-crm-2015

I have previously only created CRM applications from downloading the SDK and adding the needed dlls manually to my project.  I attempted tonight to take an existing Command Line App that I have, and do all the MS dlls required, via NuGet.  Here are the list of dlls that I need:

- Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll - Used to create a connection to CRM
- Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll - Contains all basic Microsoft CRM Types (OptionSets/Query Expressions, etc)
- Microsft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll - Contains messaging types (WhoAmIRequest)

The Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll is located in the `Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions` Nuget package.  This has a dependency on the `Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies` which contains the other two assemblies.

I installed the `Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions` and noticed that it didn't actually add the Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll to the project.  Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I noticed that it added the following references:

- AntiXSSLibrary
- Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CodeGeneration
- Microsoft.Xrm.Portal
- Microsoft.Xrm.Portal.Files
- Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment
- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- System.Data.Services
- System.Data.Services.Client
- System.Design
- System.Drawing
- System.Runtime.Caching
- System.Security
- System.ServiceModel.Web
- System.Web
- System.Web.ApplicationServices
- System.Web.Extensions
- System.Xaml
- WindowsBase

This seems rather excessive.  What is the recommended approach to adding my 3 dlls that I'm using, to my project?  Install the Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions and then manually tweak the References to get what I need?

Comment: remember that a couple of months ago I created some nuget packages (but after removed)? I made that nuget packages exactly for the problem/scenario you described, if I create a console app why I need System.Xaml or PresentionCore? Your company can create a nuget server and build custom nuget packages to be used internally

Comment: Download the CRM SDK, extract it and reference the Three packages you want manually, it's more work to create something for Three packages.

Comment: Should have been more specific @RickardN.  I wanted to do it via NuGet